# How do I delete a key from a file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a few more pieces to add sorry if my code is messy. I'm trying to delete a whole key, value from a file. These are in dictionary format with key and value. The key is the E-mail so the person enters the email to delete.

I've tried using pop and del but I'm either doing it wrong or the code leading up to it is wrong

```py
emailDict = dict()
initialQ = input("For E-mail's would you like to add, delete, lookup, or change? ")
if initialQ == "add":
    with open("C:\\TestData\\EmailList.txt","a+") as infile:
        howMany = int(input("How many people would you like to enter? "))
        for x in range(howMany):
            key = input("Please enter their E-mail: ")
            value = input("Please enter name of who the E-mail belongs to: ")
            infile.write(value+ " E-mail is ")
            infile.write(key+"\n")
            emailDict[key]= value
            print("Please make sure info is correct",emailDict)
        infile.close()
if initialQ == "delete":
with open("C:\\TestData\\EmailList.txt","r+") as infile:

    howMany = int(input("How many people would you like to delete? "))

    for x in range(howMany):

        nameDel = input("Enter the email you would like to remove: ")
        deleteP= infile.readlines()
        if nameDel in deleteP:
           del [key]
    infile.close()
```

remove the key and value from file.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
# read all the lines
with open("EmailList.txt") as infile:
    deleteP= infile.readlines()

# if you have \n at the end, strip that
deleteP = [x.strip() for x in deleteP]
print(deleteP)

howMany = int(input("How many people would you like to delete? "))

for x in range(howMany):
    nameDel = input("Enter the email you would like to remove: ")
    if nameDel in deleteP:
       deleteP.remove(nameDel)

print(deleteP)
```

**Example file**

```
> cat EmailList.txt
abc@test.com
xyz@test.com
who@test.com
123@test.com
```

**Result**

```
['abc@test.com', 'xyz@test.com', 'who@test.com', '123@test.com']
How many people would you like to delete? 2
Enter the email you would like to remove: xyz@test.com
Enter the email you would like to remove: 123@test.com
['abc@test.com', 'who@test.com']
```

Note that this will not write back the information to a file. You will have to write it back to the file yourself like so:

```
with open("EmailList.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for item in deleteP:
        outfile.write(item + "\n")
```

Comment: I tried but I think because I put it in another variable it's not working?

Comment: Can you explain what variable you added and what the outcome was?